# The src of img object doesn't work specificly for me

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make an src for an `img` element that i have in my HTML file, but for some reason, when I try to insert a source into an image,
the workspace does not recognize the `img` object as an image object, and therefore does not allow src to be inserted there.

It is important to emphasize that this problem only exists in the work environment I work with (WebStorm).
When I tried to put the code into an online work environment, it worked great.

My attempt to put src in WebStorm despite the problem like this:

HTML:

`<img id="img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">`

JS:

```
let img = document.getElementById("img");
img.src = "https:\/\/images.dog.ceo\/breeds\/terrier-toy\/n02087046_3843.jpg";
```

But it just made the work environment react with this error:

`Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')`

Comment: @Antonio Pantano As you can see in the code below the title 'HTML', I do have an ```img```object whose id is 'img'

Comment: @Calculuswhiz   here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/c4xj81a2/   it works fine there, but not in my work environment

Comment: I'm pretty certain that this is because the script is running before your page loads. Wrap your script in a function (e.g. `init`) , then call the function with the `onload` attribute `<body onload="init()">...`. The web environments typically do this for you, I think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Comment: ok, what you mentioned didn't work, but When I did it directly with ```document.getElementById``` and not by an external variable, it suddenley worked... wierd..

Comment: @Calculuswhiz sadly, the link you brought didn't answered me

Answer (score 1):

As written in the question, there are 2 (no, 3) options to fix the error.

**Option 1**: Normal string quote

```js
img.src = "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/terrier-toy/n02087046_3843.jpg";
```

**Option 2**: Add quotes around your original escaped character string

```js
img.src = "https:\/\/images.dog.ceo\/breeds\/terrier-toy\/n02087046_3843.jpg";
```

**Option 3**: Set the attribute

```js
img.setAttribute("src", "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/terrier-toy/n02087046_3843.jpg");
```

Comment: as i said in my question, the work environment doesn't even recognize the ```img``` element as an image and not even alowing me to insert an src. in my project, the src DOES have the ' ' and stil not working

Comment: @MikeHemilton - your original question **did not** have the string quoted.

Comment: yes i know. my apologize. i forgot to add it here, but now i say (and also mentioned it in my question),  the problem is the fuct that the work environment doesn't recognize the ```img``` as an image element, so i also can't insert an src... :(

Comment: @MikeHemilton - I added a 3rd option. But, I would also try changing the name of the `id` to something other than _img_: `<img id="myImg" src="xxx">` - just a wild guess that maybe your work environment is confused by the id value and img tag?

Comment: it turned out that the only way is by directly getting the element and do the change of source. it won't work if you keep the element in a variable and only then trying to change the src...

Comment: @MikeHemilton you really need to post your complete code. What you're describing does not make sense. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code. I've added `setTimeout` for 2 second just to visualize. You can remove `setTimeout` from here in your case.

```js
function changeImage() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var image = document.getElementById("img")
    image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/xNE8K6Q.jpeg"
  }, 2000)
}

changeImage()
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/hk1iahZ.jpeg" height="100" width="100" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using `setTimeout()`, why not use the `onload` attribute on the `body`?

Comment: as i said in my question, the work environment doesn't even recognize the img element as an image and not even alowing me to insert an src.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes of tags always has the string value so put your `url` as string. As per your code, you can try this:

```js
let img = document.getElementById("img");
img.src = "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/terrier-toy/n02087046_3843.jpg";
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
```

Comment: yes i know it's working here, but in my project specificly it just not. i don't know why

Comment: can you update code and share in more details as your question not describe the actual problem

Comment: make sure you have a single field with id "img"

Comment: my code looks exactly like this, but the work enviroment does not recognize it for some reason

Comment: that's exactly how my code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/c4xj81a2/ it works perfectly in the online work enviroment, but not when i do it in my project in WebStorm. i really don't know what else to say

Comment: check `$("#img").click(function(){alert("Hello")});` is working for you or not
also try with dom